# insert within a script

Tags: oracle, loops, insert

i came across a problem on PLSQL and hope i can get here some help .
i have 2 tables - the first is called test1, and has 2 columns - customer_id and msisdn and has 2 records in it.
the other one is called test_hist and has 3 columns - customer_id, msisdn and seqno and have 1 record.
"seqno" is a sequnce number. every record that's inseted get a seqno number which is higher by 1. 
the script i wrote is :

DECLARE

```
CURSOR test IS
SELECT * FROM test1; 


CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER;
MSISDN NUMBER;
V_SEQNO NUMBER;
```

BEGIN

```
    FOR a IN test LOOP

        SELECT MAX(SEQNO)+1 INTO V_SEQNO FROM test1_hist;

        INSERT INTO test1_hist
        select a.CUSTOMER_ID ,v_seqno, a.msisdn
        from test1;
    END LOOP;
    commit;
```

END;

the problem is, that after running it, this is what i get on test_hist table :

```
CUSTOMER_ID SEQNO   MSISDN

1.55443322  3   5422112
1.55443322  3   5422112
1.12232323  2   5454554
1.12232323  2   5454554
1.22211444  1   544643330
```

it runs the same times as the number of records.
if i had 4 records on test1 table, it would insert to test_hist 16 (4 of each)in total.
the original table im working with has 400k records, so i cant just do few simple insert statements.... (:
im using TOAD , the environement is ORACLE 8.

any idea what am i missing ?

thanks very much
Assaf.

Comment: What language and environment is that? Looks like SQL, but can you be more precise?

Comment: Thanks for adding that information. And sorry, no experience with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use sequence ..then there is no need for pl/sql block to insert the data..can be done in simple insert...other wise use pl/sql with dual or values

DECLARE

CURSOR test IS
SELECT * FROM test1;

```
CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER;
MSISDN NUMBER;
V_SEQNO NUMBER;
BEGIN

    FOR a IN test LOOP

        SELECT MAX(SEQNO)+1 INTO V_SEQNO FROM test1_hist;

        INSERT INTO test1_hist
        select a.CUSTOMER_ID ,v_seqno, a.msisdn
        from dual;
    END LOOP;
    commit;
```

Comment: i AM actually tryin to understand how does dual work, especially on this example

Comment: Hi Shlomix,
the problem was if you were trying to insert each value the into table test1_hist as much times as in test1 table ....
please run a query like 
select '<string>' from test1;
this would return '<string>' as much times as number of columns in test1..
But when it comes to dual...it would return only row.
for Example run this query select * from dual; this would return only single row...
thats inorder to loop in pl/sql and insert individual values then you should have to use insert into <table_name > values() clause or insert into <tablename> select values from dual;

Comment: please let me know if any more clarification is need

Comment: Hi GKV.
thanks very much for the informative reply. i understand now (: . i tried both ways - the dual and values() and both work. thanks again.